# What is this 喜迎十九大 event all over the recent Chinese news?

Tags: culture

A few days ago, I was browsing around CCTV and I found this page labeled "喜迎十九大", with the hammer and sickle next to it and I was immediately interested.

http://news.cctv.com/special/xysjd/index.shtml

I have yet to find a good translation for the phrase "喜迎十九大", which I'm sure means something other than "welcome nineteen big". Can anyone please help explain to me this event? Many thanks in advance for any responses.

Comment: Joyous Greetings to the 19th National Congress of the Communist Party of China!  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/19th_National_Congress_of_the_Communist_Party_of_China

Comment: 十九大 is the abbreviated form of (中国共产党)第**十九**次全国代表**大**会, the 19th national congress (of the Communist Party of China).

Comment: 喜迎十九大 should mean **Welcome the 19th national congress**

Answer (score 3):

喜迎 → Welcome (with fond)
十九大 is an abbreviation for 中国共产党第**十九**次全国代表**大**会. The 19th National Congress of the Communist Party of China.

It's an upcoming event starting on October 18, 2017. As a bad custom, Chinese news media have started propagation about such important events since a few months ago. It'd be absolutely normal to see a truckload of these spams.